# TinyXml2 stream printing

Tags: c++, tinyxml2

How can I set a XMLDocument for stream printing in TinyXML-2?

Im trying to port code from TinyXML-1 to TinyXML-2. In TinyXML-1, I could do something like:

```
TinyXmlPrinter myPrinter;
myDocument.Accept(&myPrinter)
myPrinter.SetStreamPrinting();
myPrinter.CStr();
```

I already have a XMLDocument built, and now im not sure how I can modify it for stream printing. The `XMLPrinter::OpenElement`, `XMLPrinter::PushAttribute` and `XMLPrinter::CloseElement` seems pretty close from what I want. So do I have to iterate all my XMLDocument and call those functions for each element, or is there a more simple way?

Comment: According to http://www.grinninglizard.com/tinyxml2docs/classtinyxml2_1_1_x_m_l_printer.html `XMLPrinter printer; doc.Print( &printer ); SomeFunction( printer.CStr() );`

Comment: @JerryJeremiah I think he would also want to set the compact argument of the constructor to true which seems to be the equivalent to SetStreamPrinting().

Comment: @AnonMail Thanks! I was missing the compact argument. :P

Answer (score 0):

As @JerryJeremiah and @AnonMail pointed out in the comments, setting compact argument to true in the printer constructor and then calling the `XMLPrinter::Print` function worked.

```
XMLPrinter myPrinter(0, true, 0); // Set compact to true
myDocument.Print(&myPrinter);
someFunction(myPrinter.CStr());
```